# Which one is better in bootstrap offset or empty div?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

```
<div class="col-xs-3"></div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6" style="min-width: 320px;">
</div>

OR


<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3 " style="min-width: 320px;">`
</div>
```

I don't want offset when width is less than or equal to 768px

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is better

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" style="min-width: 320px;"></div>
```

with this the offset work only width > 768px

bye

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking whether you should use an empty div to help layout a page then no. You should avoid using meaningless markup if the same job can be easily done with css.